# mod_pagespeed drops headers

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-pagespeed

I have installed mod_pagespeed in Apache. It drops header `X-UA-Compatible`. When I turned of mod_pagespeed `X-UA-Compatible` appear in headers. Have anyone idea how to disable this in mod_pagespeed?

My `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is setting that header?

Comment: I'm setting it in my .htaccess file – see update in question.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but try adding `early` to the end of the `Header` line?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same kind of problem (Setcookie header was dropped by mod_pagespeed, which made sessions impossible to use).

In my case, it was caused by the flush() function in my PHP code.

Apparently mod_pagespeed only kept headers set AFTER the last flush, discarding all headers defined before :-/

Hope this can help...